# MySQL syntax error on escaped string

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

MySQL is giving a 1064 on an escaped string.

```
$date is set above.
$article_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$article);
$guid_clean= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$guid_clean);
$pub_date_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$pub_date);
$title_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$title);
$query = "INSERT INTO blog_post (date,article,link,pub_date,title) VALUES ('$date',$article_clean','$guid_clean','$pub_date_clean','$title_clean')";

mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
```

Why?

Comment: @piotrm THANK YOU!!!! I guess after a few hours I should take a break.

Comment: Just something I noted, if you're using mysqli, why don't you use prepared statements?

Comment: @Mike  I guess I don't know about those. Do you have any information on that?

Comment: Prepared statements are one of the main advantages of mysqli instead of mysql_* functions. Check the documentation here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed a single quote, Rewrite your query line with this one:-

```
$query = "INSERT INTO blog_post (date,article,link,pub_date,title) VALUES ('$date','$article_clean','$guid_clean','$pub_date_clean','$title_clean')";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO blog_post (blah blah) VALUES ('$date',$article_clean', ...)";
                                                            ^
```

You have no opening quote for this argument. You need to add one.

On top of that, this statement looks suspicious:

```
$guid_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string ($dbc, $guid_clean);
```

All the others act on the "unclean" version to produce the clean one. Unless you've already set `guid_clean` somehow, it *probably* should be:

```
$guid_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string ($dbc, $guid);
```

As I say, that's not *necessarily* the case but I'd check it to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get a better PHP IDE to get over these problems easily.

Comment: Eclipse is quite good. I am using PHPStorm now. There is a trial version available, you can give it a try.